# Seelnium File Upload Test

Tags: javascript, selenium, file-upload

I am able to reach an HTML tag on OneDrive(logged in account), which helps uplaod a file.

```
driver.findElement(By.css("div[class='ContextualMenu-uploadInput']"));
```

On applying `.click()` to this, I am able to get the file selection pop up, which means I can select file for upload.

There are tonnes of articles out there that mention how to upload a file using selenium.

However, after trying myriad examples that pass the path from local to upload files, or using external services like SauceLabs, I am unable to upload a file.

Is there a way Selenium handles the file selection pop up ?

Any recommendations will be a great help.

Also, please follow [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765650/upload-files-to-onedrive-or-any-such-private-cloud-storage-using-selenium-test) for a comprehensive insight.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Simple google search test
 */

test.describe('One Drive Test', function() {
  var driver;

  test.before(function () {
    driver = new Driver();
  });

  test.after(function () {
    driver.quit();
  });

  test.it('should append query to title', function() {
    driver.get('https://onedrive.live.com/');
    var srch = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("i[class='od-IconGlyph ms-Icon ms-Icon--Upload od-IconGlyph--visible']")), 10000);

    srch.click();

    var getFileUpl = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("div[class='ContextualMenu-uploadInput']")), 10000);

    driver.sleep(5000);
  });

});
```

Comment: Can you provide a concrete [mcve] that we can have a look at? It is the way to get the best answers at SO.

Comment: @A.Kootstra please find it in the question. I added it and want to write a line of code that'd help me upload file to that tag.
Thanks

Comment: Selenium cannot interact with the dialog. It is an operating system dialog that is separate from the browser.

Comment: @RonNorris Thanks. Exactly what I expected. Any other heads up about uploading files???

Comment: @vedlociraptor, you knew that Selenium cannot interact with desktop windows. Instead you can use AutoIT code to select/click/close dekstop windows